# Showing that the symmetric subspace of N copies of the fundamental representation space is the space of the n-th irrep for SU(2).

Tags: representation-theory

I would like to have a clear explanation of why the symmetric subspace of N copies of the fundamental representation space is the space of the n-th irrep for SU(2) (and also more generally I don't know?).

I can see for two spin half objects $\frac{1}{2}\otimes \frac{1}{2}$ one can choose the multiplet and singlet as a basis $\{|00>,|01>+|10>,|11>\}$ and $\{|01>-|10>\}$. So one can say that the largest of the spaces in the Clebsch-Gordan decomposition ($1\oplus 0$) is indeed the space $sym(H^2\otimes H^2)$

I'm not clear however how to move beyond this. In an intuitive sense I can see that if I take some symmetric subspace of  $sym(H^{2n})$ I could view it in terms of a basis made up of sums of vectors where one has 1 in every possible position i.e |000>,|010>+|100>+|001>,|110>+|101>+|011>,|111>. However in this case I can't quite see how to link this to being the space of the nth (spin 3/2 in my example) irrep as determined by the Clebsch-Gordan decomposition (which would guarantee it was an irrep at least).

I suppose another way of phrasing the question is why is the largest space in the Clebsch-Gordan decomposition of n copies of the fundamental representations the symmetric subspace of those copies? (And is this just a property of SU(2)?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case there is no need of the Clebsch-Gordan decomposition, you can really do things more concretely with basis elements.

Let $V = \mathbb C^2$ be the fundamental rep of $\mathfrak{su}_2$ with basis $e_1,e_2$. You should have elements $x,y \in \mathfrak{su}_2$ such that $x e_1 = e_2, xe_2 = 0$ and $ye_2 = e_1, ye_1 = 0$.

A basis of $Sym^n(V)$ is given by $e_1^n,e_1^{n-1}e_2, \dots, e_2^n$. Then, it's easy to see that from $e_1^n$ you can get the whole $Sym^n(V)$ by applying $x$ several times, for example $x \cdot e_1^n = ne_1^{n-1}e_2, x^2e_1^n = x(ne_1^{n-1}e_2) = n(n-1)e_1^{n-2}e_2^2$, etc ...

It follows that $Sym^n(V)$ is irreducible.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  As a novice in this I've a few questions.You look at the lie algerba rather than the group, why is this? I see x and y allow one to move through the basis, but I'm not clear on why there must exist an elements s.t $xe^n = ne^{n-1}$? Is  $Sym^n(V)$ my $sym(V{\otimes n})$? Finally, and most importantly, it's not obvious to me why this shows all shows $Sym^n(V)$ is irreducible. Apologies for the barrage of questions but I thought it would be efficient to simply pick out exactly what confuses me. P.S is there a reference for this stuff, I couldn't find it in Hall etc?